# javaee module class-loading and static variables

Tags: java, glassfish, jboss7.x, classloader, wildfly-8

Consider the following: support.jar

```
public class SupportUtil{

  private static Map<String, Resource> myResources;

  void init(){
    initResources();
  }
}
```

Then i have 2 independent war applications conneting remotely to another ejb module within the same javaee server (currently using wildfly 8)

```
war1 -> lib/support.jar
war2 -> lib/support.jar
ejb1 -> ear-lib/support.jar
```

My questions is, based on module classloading architecture, would the three modules see the same Map off myResources (considering that this is a class variable, and class variables are shared by all instances)

I need clarification, for wildfly or glassfish, how classloading would affect this behaviour.

Comment: Once the class has been loaded `myResources` which is static would be loaded along with it, and the same copy of it will be shared with all your modules until there are references to the class.

Comment: @DarshanLila would the same classloader (read same instance of ModuleClassLoader) load SupportUtil for the three modules? Mark you, these are independent deployment units.

Answer (score 1):

> The war is considered to be a single module, so classes defined in WEB-INF/lib are treated the same as classes in WEB-INF/classes. All classes packaged in the war will be loaded with the same class loader.
>
> By default the EAR/lib directory is a single module, and every WAR or EJB jar deployment is also a separate module.

Each module will load its own class instance with its own static field values.

> Sub deployments (wars and ejb-jars) always have a dependency on the parent module, which gives them access to classes in EAR/lib, however they do not always have an automatic dependency on each other. This behaviour is controlled via the ear-subdeployments-isolated setting in the ee subsystem configuration.

WARs usually depend on EAR/lib. So your WAR modules would "see" two instances of `SupportUtil`. When the code executes in the WAR module context (during a web application request), it would see it's own lib instance of `SupportUtil`. When you WAR calls EJB remotely (or even locally!) then the module context switches to EJB, and the "current" instance of `SupportUtil` comes from the EAR/lib module. (Disclaimer: I didn't test this, but that's my understanding.)

I wouldn't advise getting into this position, when a module has access to multiple instances of the same class. I don't have any failure stories to back that up, it just seems to be a potential source of confusion: a code in the same module can see different values depending on how the execution got there.

There is a special case though.

> The ear-subdeployments-isolated element value has no effect on the isolated classloader of the .war file(s). i.e. irrespective of whether this flag is set to true or false, the .war within a .ear will have a isolated classloader and other sub-deployments within that .ear will not be able to access classes from that .war. This is as per spec.

WARs are always isolated! So you could have the same jars/classes in multiple WARs, and no module will see more multiple instances of the same classes.

Source: [Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly).